# How can I get just the first word from an address link text with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<a title="Home" href="#">Home test test</a>
```

I can use a.html() to get me "Home test test" but what I need is just the first word "Home". Is there an easy way that I can do this with jQuery?

Comment: `.html()` or `.text()` will be the same for this situation. Typically, you should use `.text()` if you are specifically trying to parse the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/HvFMp/

split: (further read if you keen) http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

**another demo using match** http://jsfiddle.net/LAKqB/ (using match)

**code**

```
$.fn.ready(function(){

  alert($('a').html().split(' ')[0]);    

});
​
```

**code using match api**

```
$.fn.ready(function(){
  var str = $("a").text().match(/\w+/);

  alert(str);     

});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

use `split()` function in javascript.

```
var str = a.html();
alert(str.split()[0]);
```

this will return 'Home' only;

Answer (score 1):

if its the string of `"Home test test"` then you can use split and get the first index in that array: `a.html().split(' ')[0]` ([split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on space so you get an array of: `["Home", "test", "test"]`)